# selecting time range for creating an event not working in month view

Tags: jquery-ui, fullcalendar

Selecting time range  on month view doesn't  work  on  certain  devices on  fullcalendar v3.8 and  jquery-ui v1.11.4 .I wasn't  able to  debug cause it works  on  most   of the  devices  only  on certain devices the draggable doesn't get  captured  on  second half of the days rectangular box.  if it  dragged  on the upper half it works.
[image]

Comment: More likely to be browser-specific than device-specific, since JavaScript runs within the browser sandbox, not on the device or operating system. Info about problematic browsers (and versions of those browsers) would be helpful.

Comment: P.S. fullCalendar doesn't require jQueryUI or Draggable for selecting time ranges, so I'm unclear why you mentioned that part. Can you show your code please?

Comment: Also, if devices where you have problems are touch devices, then have you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/touch? These settings can affect how you make selections on a touch interface.

Comment: Lastly you mention fullCalendar 3.8. Have you tried to upgrade to the latest version (3.10) to see if that makes any difference? I'm not aware what fixes are in there or if they are relevant to this functionality, but you could look and see

Comment: upgrading to full calendar(3.10)  fixed the issue.thanks for the help